# How to make my character Double jump with this code?(newbie)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want double jump but not much idea to do! managed single jump by far.
Followed some youtube tutorials and some articles however none of them worked for me I know I am doing wrong because I am not familiar with c# .

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine;

public class Walk_script : MonoBehaviour 
{
  public float speed = 4;
  public float gravity = 8;
  public float jumpSpeed = 5.0f;

  Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
  CharacterController controller;
  Animator anim;

  // Start is called before the first frame update
  void Start()
  {
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update()
  {
    if (controller.isGrounded)
    {
      if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
      {
        anim.SetBool("running", true);
        moveDirection = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
        moveDirection *= speed;
      }

      if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
      {
        anim.SetBool("running", false);
        moveDirection = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
      }

      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
      {
        anim.SetBool("jump", true);
        moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
      }
      else
      {
        anim.SetBool("jump", false);
      }
    }
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're only running your jump code when `isGrounded = false`. Instead you should bound it to a jump counter of some kind. Lets say we make an integer variable `jumping = 0`.  Say `if (jumping < 2) //Jump`. Then when you do jump, do `jumping++`. Reset `jumping = 0` when you touch the ground. There are better ways to do this im sure but this one is pretty easy and intuitive to understand.

Comment: You should put this as an answer. It is the answer, after all.

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard Can you please write this? I am not much ok with c#

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout [this](http://answers.unity.com/answers/643243/view.html) answer for a proper jump and double jump implementation but here is your code with double jump.

You need to manage hasJumped boolean to check if you can jump again while in the air.
Set it to true when jumped while on the ground and check if it's true so you can jump again only once while in the air.

```
 bool hasJumped = false;
    // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
     if (controller.isGrounded)
     {
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
         {
            anim.SetBool("running", true);
            moveDirection = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
            moveDirection *= speed;
         }

         if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
         {
            anim.SetBool("running", false);
            moveDirection = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
         }

         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
         {
            anim.SetBool("jump", true);
            hasJumped = true;
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
         }
         else
         {
            anim.SetBool("jump", false);
         }
     }
     else
     {
         if (hasJumped && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
          {
             Debug.Log("Second Jump");
             anim.SetBool("jump", true);
             hasJumped = false;
             moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
          }
     }

     moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
     controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
 }
```